# Добавление вертикальной полосы прокрутки в AlertDialog в Android

Tags: java, android

Я добавил скролл поместив компоненты из `LinearLayout` в `<ScrollView>` в  итоге сам `layout` виден полностью, но кнопки подтверждения `AlertDialog` не видно, оно и понятно. Но как добавить полосу прокрутки для `AlertDialog`?
Для наглядности прикрепляю [скриншот](https://image.ibb.co/kuVR38/1.png).

Comment: Кнопки тоже Ваши или стандартные? У `<ScrollView>` размеры `math_parent`?

Comment: создавая вопросы про разметку(верстку) желательно видеть код, вам скопировать и вставить, а ответ получите гораздо точней, быстрей и качественней.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло установить размеры `<ScrollView>` на `math_parent`